# PostgreSql results printing to console but not displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, console

I'm trying to get some data from a pg database to my api endpoint , I can print the results to the console but I can't get them to display in the browser with res.send. I'm guessing the problem is with global and local scope however I've not been able to figure it out. I'm using ES6 but transpiling with babel. Here's a snippet.

```
app.get('/', (request, response) => {


const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');
const config = {
  user: '',
  host: '',
  database: '',
  password: '',
  port: ,
}

const pool = new Pool(config);
const client = new Client(config);

let whole = [];
client.connect();
const text = "SELECT * FROM entries where id='1'";

client.query(text)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.rows[0]);
  whole.push(res.rows[0]);
})
.catch(e => console.error(e.stack));

response.send(whole);
client.end;
  });
```

This logs to the console

```
{ id: 1, title: 'First title', body: 'beautiful body' }
```

However the browser only displays []
This is what babel transpiles it to which is the script I run in node.

```
var whole = [];
client.connect();
var text = "SELECT * FROM entries where id='1'";

client.query(text).then(function (res) {
  console.log(res.rows[0]);
  whole.push(res.rows[0]);
}).catch(function (e) {
  return console.error(e.stack);
});

response.send(whole);
client.end;
```

Comment: Side note: `where id='1'` i assume id column is a INT datatype if so drop the quotes in your query..

Answer (score 0):

response.send is called outside of the async promise .then resolver, and is therefore executed before you push the row data into the array. Moving response.send into the promise resolver should fix it.

```
client.query(text).then(res => {
  whole.push(res.rows[0]);
  client.end();
  response.send(whole);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.error(e.stack);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use async/await depending on your babel version and presets/plugins.

```
const { Client } = require("pg");
const config = {...};
const queryText = "SELECT * FROM entries where id='1'";

app.get("/", async (request, response) => {
  const client = new Client(config);
  await client.connect();

  try {
    const queryResponse = await client.query(queryText);
    // Send response without pushing to array
    response.send(queryResponse.rows[0]);
    client.end();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.stack);
  }
});
```

Comment: I still have problems with returning values from the .then resolver. I can print values to the console but I can't return anything with the return statement.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the second part of my answer where I was calling `res.send` instead of `response.send`. Example is updated to reflect working code.

Comment: No problem. already used the first part and it works.But I can't return anything from a function with `return res.rows` I can get it to work with api calls `response.send` but not with normal functions